# Find two constants that when multiplied by vectors gives you another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If we have vector $A = 5{i} -2j  $ ,$B = -4i + 3 j $ and $C = 5i - 4 j$. How can I find two constants $h$ and $k$ such that $C = hA+kB$?

Thanks.

Comment: Project $A$ onto $C$ (to get $h$) and $B$ onto $C$ (to get $k$).

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening just use that $i=(1,0)$ and $j=(0,1)$

$C=(hA_1+kB_1,hA_2+kB_2)$

$A=(A_1,A_2)=(5,-2)$ and $B=(B_1,B_2)=(-4,3)$ and $C=(C_1,C_2)=(5,-4)$

Thus $(5,-4)=(5h-4k,-2h+3k)$

That gives you a system of two equations.

Comment: Did you mean $-2h+3k$ where you typed $-2h-4k$?

Comment: Yep, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

C = 5i - 4j = hA + kB,

5i - 4j = h(5i-2j) + k(-4i+3j)

5i - 4j = (5h-4k)i + (-2h+3k)j

System of two equations

5h -4k = 5

-2h +3k =4

Now you can finish :)

Answer (score 0):

You've been given that $ C = hA + kB$ which in matrix form is:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
5 \\ 
-4 \end{bmatrix}
= h \begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-2
\end{bmatrix} + k
\begin{bmatrix}
-4\\
3
\end{bmatrix} $

$ = \begin{bmatrix}
5h\\
-2h
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
-4k\\
3k \end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
5h - 4k\\
-2h + 3k
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -4\\
-2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h\\
k
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let's denote this matrix by $ \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -4\\
-2 & 3
\end{bmatrix} = M $ and its inverse by $M^{-1}.$

$\implies M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
5\\
-4
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
h\\
k
\end{bmatrix}$

Please tell me you know how to calculate $M^{-1}$ and can solve this now for $h$ and $k$.